# What is the best way to design related entities of the same nature (ie: Related Articles)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am looking an efficient way to design and code the following business requirement:
In a knowledge base application, I need to code a "Related Article(s)" feature that allows the user to relate articles to an existing article. This would help to minimize dublins and also make the search smarter and faster.

My specs:

- Database: PostgreSQL 9.0.3
- Persistence framework: EJB 3
- Application server: jBoss 4.2.3GA
- Web App Framework : Struts 1.3.5

Here is the way I have designed my SQL tables:

- Table: Article (primary key is intId)
- Table: RelatedArticle (primary is a composition intArticleId and intRelatedArticleId, both columns would reference Article).

Is it a good way to do it?

Thank you guys

Charles

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need here is at least one `@Entity` on your `Article` table / domain object, with a `@OneToMany` to your `RelatedArticles` table/domain object.  We've used discriminator values in the past to allow us not to have a join table like this.  In your case, depending on whether or not you're going to be building complex join queries, you might be better off with straight JDBC for your join columns.

However, it's not a far-cry to just build two Entity domain objects and annotate them properly to achieve what your after, I don't think.